# Unnecessary Scrollbar in Chrome 76 on WIndows 10

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, view

```
   <div style="overflow-x: hidden">
      <div style="height: 100%">
        <p style="margin-bottom: 1rem">
          asdf dasfd asdf asdfsdf dasfd asdf asdfsdf dasfd asdf asdfsdf dasfd asdf asdfsdf dasfd asdf asdfsdf dasfd asdf asdf
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x6kmf507/1/

This code shows extra scollbar only in Windows 10 and Chrome 76. Why? And how fix it?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove Height for that div or add there `overflow:hidden`

```html
 <div style="overflow-x: hidden">
      <div>
        <p style="margin-bottom: 1rem">
          asdf dasfd asdf asdfsdf dasfd asdf asdfsdf dasfd asdf asdfsdf dasfd asdf asdfsdf dasfd asdf asdfsdf dasfd asdf asdf
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: OK. I think that the solution with overflow:hidden at div with 100% height is the best solution for this bug.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `height: 100%;` from the second div it will remove the scrollbar.

I assume there is a reason for your nested divs. Can you provide more context to why you are formatting the html the way you are?

Comment: It was really difficult to identify the problem - the real code is enormous.

Comment: I know if I remove overflow-x or height or margin then scrolbar hides but this styles are from foreign components. It´s a bug? It works on linux and an other browsers only on Windows 10 and chrome is wrong.

Comment: I actually saw the scrollbar on mac chrome as well. The problem here is the margin on the p tag. The middle div height 100% is based on the parent div's height and that div doesn't respond to the margin of the grandchild.

Comment: But why does It work If I remove "overflow-x: hidden" on the root div? Or It is also working if I add border to the middle div. Strange.